# How do I enable emoji button in vanilla GNOME keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, gnome-shell

On login screen, the keyboard looks like

[image]

But in user session, the emoji key is missing

[image]

Interestingly, emoji key is absent from Ubuntu GNOME too.

[image]

I'm using vanilla GNOME on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Is that an emoji button? On KDE log in screen, that key just makes a `:)` for some reason. Back on Unity with onboard (I think this is a fork of onboard) you would just press the `?123` key a couple of times to get the emoji layout. I guess that is not quite what you wanted but this keyboard is criminally under documented, I couldn't find even a mention of that button.

Comment: @MarkKirby Pressing `?123` multiple times doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard-coded to show the emoji button only in `wayland` sessions. Hence the GDM Login Screen is not effected and emoji button is shown on the login screen.

When you choose `wayland` session, the emoji button is shown.

---

**How to enable it on XORG?**

***Option 1.***
Report/Request it to GNOME developers for future releases

***Option 2.***
creation of `gnome-shell-extension` by experts is required to remove the check whether the session is `wayland`? and do the same job for both the sessions.

Ubuntu on Wayland
[image]

GNOME (Vanilla gnome installed and checked)
[image]